# Update Background via the commandline Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, 22.04, gsettings

I have a script that I have been running for years on my computer that updates the background image to a new image every minute and functions as a clock. I was wondering how to update the desktop background image via the command line. I had used to use `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///path/to/file` however that does not seem to be working. I had confirmed that I am the owner of `~/.config/dconf` and am able to edit the folder. If anyone has any advise that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @NickGoraika, are you using a systemwide DARK theme? in 22.04 a new key is introduced. picture-uri-dark. `org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Mirror_by_Uday_Nakade.jpg'
org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark 'file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png'
`

Comment: if that does not help, can you provide the script file to further investigate where is the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script probably will work if you switch to using the light theme. Starting with Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome Shell 42), the background when using a dark theme is controlled by a different setting, `org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark`. This allows to establish different backgrounds depending on whether you use the light of the dark theme.

Thus, update your script to have it change `picture-uri-dark`.

Comment: I am using a system wide dark mode and would rather not be blinded by the light mode `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri-dark "file:///path/to/file"` worked great. I really appreciate the help. Thank you